# Angularjs 2 TypeError: Cannot read property 'infos' of undefined with the Http Client

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, rest, typescript

I have been working on an angularjs app since a good week now. I am building a backoffice application for my service.

I am having trouble using data fetched frome a remote server. I have 4 http GET request in my app, 2 of them are fetching list of users and orders, those ones work fine but the 2 others, fetching user details and order details give me the same error.

Here is the error I get for the user details:

[Console error when trying to display user details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1r26.png)

Here is the component (user-details.component.ts):

```
import {Component}          from 'angular2/core';
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES}  from 'angular2/router';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS}     from 'angular2/http';

import {UserDetailsModel}   from '../model/user-details.model';
import {UserDetailsService} from '../service/user-details.service';
import {Configuration}      from '../app.constants';

@Component({
    selector: 'user-details',
    templateUrl: 'app/template/user-details.component.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [UserDetailsService, HTTP_PROVIDERS, Configuration]
})

export class UserDetailsComponent {

    errorMessage: string;
    userDetailsModel: UserDetailsModel[];

    constructor (private _userDetailsService: UserDetailsService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getUserDetails();
    }

    getUserDetails() {
        this._userDetailsService.getUserDetails()
                          .subscribe(
                            userDetailsModel => this.userDetailsModel = userDetailsModel,
                            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    }

}
```

Here is the service (user-details.service.ts):

```
import {Injectable}         from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, Response}     from 'angular2/http';
import {Observable}         from 'rxjs/Observable';

import {UserDetailsModel}  from '../model/user-details.model';
import {Configuration}      from '../app.constants';

@Injectable()
export class UserDetailsService {

    constructor (private _http: Http, private _config: Configuration) {

        this._actionUrl = _config.serverUrl + 'users/40';

    }
    private _actionUrl: string;


    getUserDetails () {
        return this._http.get(this._actionUrl)
                         .map(res => <UserDetailsModel[]> res.json().user)
                         .do(user => console.log(user))
                         .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private handleError (error: Response) {
        // in a real world app, we may send the error to some remote logging infrastructure
        // instead of just logging it to the console
        console.error(error);
        return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
    }
}
```

Here is the model (user-details.model.ts):

```
export class Address {
    constructor (
        public type:                string,
        public address:             string,
        public additional_info:     string,
        public zip_code:            string,
        public city:                string,
        public floor:               number,
        public elevator:            boolean
    ) { }
}

export class Infos {
    constructor (
        public username:    string,
        public email:       string,
        public first_name:  string,
        public last_name:   string,
        public birth_date:  string,
        public gender:      string,
        public telephone:   string
    ) { }
}

export class UserDetailsModel {
  constructor(
    public infos:    Infos[],
    public adresses: Address[]
  ) {  }
}
```

Here is the a part of the template where I use the data fetch from the server (user-details.template.ts):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <img class="img-thumbail" src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
        <p>Rating xxxx</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <p>Nom : {{userDetailsModel.infos[0].last_name}}</p>
        <p>Prénom : {{userDetailsModel.infos[0].first_name}}</p>
        <p>Date de naissance : {{userDetailsModel.infos[0].birth_date}}</p>
        <p>Adresse : {{userDetailsModel.adresses[0].address}}</p>
        <p>Code postal : {{userDetailsModel.adresses[0].zip_code}}</p>
        <p>Villee : {{userDetailsModel.adresses[0].city}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <p>E-mail : {{userDetailsModel.infos[0].email}}</p>
        <p>Téléphone : {{userDetailsModel.infos[0].telephone}}</p>
        <p>Note moyenne </p>
        <p>Courtoisie</p>
        <p>Donne un coup de main</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And finally, here is the json response I get from the API call:

```
{
  "detail": "success"
  "user": {
    "infos": [1]
     0:  {
     "username": "john.doe@domain.com"
     "email": "john.doe@domain.com"
     "first_name": "Johan"
     "last_name": "Doe"
     "birth_date": "1994-07-09T05:00:00.000Z"
     "gender": "M"
     "telephone": "0612365478"
  }-
-
  "adresses": [1]
    0:  {
     "type": "Principal"
     "address": "2 place du chateau"
     "additional_info": null
     "zip_code": "35500"
     "city": "VITRE"
     "floor": null
     "elevator": null
    }-
  -
  }-
}
```

Thanks in advance for taking a look, I hope you'll help me find what did I do wrong.

**EDIT:**
I have added a directive "*ngIf="userDetailsModel" inside the main  wrapping the template and now it works fine. In fact the template was running and tried accessing the object properties before the actual http request was done retrieving the data.

Comment: It seems that `Info` & `Address` has property in constructor, that should be moved out in a class itself.

Comment: What do you mean ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're defining userDetailsModel as an array of UserDetails:

```
userDetailsModel: UserDetailsModel[];
```

If that's the case, you need to specify an index when using it.

```
userDetailsModel[x].propertyName
```

Otherwise declare it as an instance of UserDetailsModel:

```
userDetailsModel: UserDetaislModel
```

Comment: Yeah I did it this way, I forgot to change it back as an object not an array of object (it's when I tried something else)

Comment: ok, so does that resolve the issue when you make it an object instead of an array?

Comment: It helps, but what really solved it, is by adding the "*ngIf=userDetailsModel" inside the main <div> in the template. The template tried to access the object before the get request to the API was done. That's what solved my problem, and I of course had to make it an object instead of an array.